# Linux C Socket: Blocked on recv call

Tags: linux, sockets, recv

In my application i have created a thread for a simple http server, then from within my application i tried to connect to http server but control is blocked/hanged on recv call.

But if try to connect to my application's http server using linux GET command, I will be connected to http server successfully.

As per my understanding by searching the google i found that this is not the right approach.

But if i want to do this, in what should i create the sockets so that i can connect o my http server from within the application.

**Below is how my http server socket created**

```
pthread_create(&pt_server, NULL, http_srvr, NULL);

//http server handler
void *http_server()
{
    int sockfd, new_fd;             
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;     
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr;  
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes=1;

    if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
    }

    if (setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(int)) == -1)
    {
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(1);
    }

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;               // host byte order
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(HTTP_PORT);        // short, network byte order
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;       // automatically fill with my IP
    memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);       // zero the rest of the struct

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))== -1)
    {
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
    }

    printf("Listening to sockets\n");
    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1)
    {
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1)
    {
    perror("sigaction");
    exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        if ((new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr,&sin_size)) == -1)
        {
          perror("accept");
          continue;
        }
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n",inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr));

        handle_connection(new_fd);
    }
}
```

**And following is how i am doing http POST to my http server**

```
  /* create socket */
  if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    return ERRSOCK;
  setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, 0, 0);


  /* connect to server */
  if (connect(s, &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) 
    ret=ERRCONN;
  else {
    if (pfd) *pfd=s;

    /* create header */
    if (proxy) {
      sprintf(header,
"%s http://%.128s:%d/%.256s HTTP/1.0\015\012User-Agent: %s\015\012%s\015\012",
          command,
          http_server1,
          http_port,
          url,
          http_user_agent,
          additional_header
          );
    } else {
      sprintf(header,
"%s /%.256s HTTP/1.0\015\012User-Agent: %s\015\012%s\015\012",
          command,
          url,
          http_user_agent,
          additional_header
          );
    }

    hlg=strlen(header);


    /* send header */   
    if (send(s,header,hlg,0)!=hlg)
      ret= ERRWRHD;

    /* send data */
    else if (length && data && (send(s,data,length,0)!=length) )
      ret= ERRWRDT;

    else {
      /* read result & check */
      ret=http_read_line(s,header,MAXBUF-1);
```

**and following are the contents of http_read_line, and in this function recv call blocked**

```
static int http_read_line (fd,buffer,max) 
     int fd; /* file descriptor to read from */
     char *buffer; /* placeholder for data */
     int max; /* max number of bytes to read */
{ /* not efficient on long lines (multiple unbuffered 1 char reads) */
  int n=0;
  while (n<max) {
    if (recv(fd,buffer,1,0)!=1) {
      n= -n;
      break;
    }
    n++;
    if (*buffer=='\015') continue; /* ignore CR */
    if (*buffer=='\012') break;    /* LF is the separator */
    buffer++;
  }
  *buffer=0;
  return n;
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. Show your code please.

Comment: updated the question witht code

Comment: Nikolai is giving you the answer.  One other point. The way your code is written now, I could write a rogue client that connects to your server, but doesn't "send" any data. Then your server code would hang indefinitely. You really should think about non-blocking sockets, timeouts, handling multiple connections in parallel, select/poll, etc..

Comment: @MA1, I think you are just mis-interpreting HTTP. Look at what your server sends on the wire with `tcpdump` or `wireshark`, and check the assumptions in your client code.

Comment: selbie and Nikolai...Thanks...I will check your suggestions.

Comment: @MAI, may I pl. know if have you  also used  this http_read_line function in the server and the recv is blocked there? I can see this function in the client side only. or you are blocked in this function in the client only?

Comment: Dont assume send() and recieve() process the amount of characters that you give to them (in the 3rd argument). BTW: `if (recv(fd,buffer,1,0)!=1) {...}` This is terrible. You spend one system call just to fetch one character from the kernel buffers. It could also block (or return 0, or -1 with EAGAIN/ EWOULDBLOCK) please read the manpages for read()/ write() et.al.

Comment: @Tanmoy: recv is used on client side only so i am blocked in client only.

Comment: @wildplasser: This whole code is not written by me, i am a newbie to network programming and just experimenting to see and learn how things are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have told "In my application i have created a thread for a simple http server, then from within my application 
    i tried to  connect to http server but control is blocked/hanged on recv call."

That means the recv is never returning 0. Now when the recv function will 
    return a 0? ->When it gets a TCP FIN segment. It seems that your server is never
    sending a TCP FIN segment to the client.
    The reason that is most likely here is that, your client code needs modification.
    You are sending data from from the client, but you are never sending the FIN,
    so I assume that your server function is continuing forever and it had not
    sent the FIN. This made the recv wait for ever.

In the current code perhaps the fix is to add a line

```
else {
  /*Send the FIN segment, but we can still read the socket*/
  shutdown(s, SHUT_WR); 
  /* read result & check */
  ret=http_read_line(s,header,MAXBUF-1);
```

In this case the shutdown function sends the TCP FIN and the server function can return and possibly then it would do a proper close.

And on a proper close, the FIN from the server will be received by the client. This would  make the recv return 0, instead of getting blocked for ever.

Now if you want to continue any further data transfer from the client, you need to again connect or may be you need to have some different algorithm.

I hope my explanation may help fix the current problem.

Comment: Might work, might not. It might cause the server to abort the hole thing. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check it. I am just learning Networking Programming so its taking time to understand the things.

Comment: @MAI, I would suggest to please read the TCP's feature once so that the connection inititation, data transfer and connection termination feature becomes clear.Then these type of problems can be solved. After this you may please check how actually you will be doing the http parsing.I suggested my solution of shutdown, so that after doing this you will possibly have a clear view of  the 4 way handshake, while connection termination.

Comment: @Tanmoy: Great Thanks. Your solution worked. Can you kindly suggest a good book on Sockets/Network Programming? what about this book? http://www.amazon.com/TCP-Sockets-Bundle-Practical-Programmers/dp/0123745403/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1339667562&sr=1-1&keywords=socket

Comment: @MA1, Thanks MAI. I have not read the book that you have reffered. I can suggest a standard classic book,  UNIX Network Programming, by W. Richard Stevens http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Network-Programming-Networking-Sockets/dp/013490012X and please also refer this Socket Faq link for further studies, which is excellent http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/socket/

Comment: This suggestion is a violation of the HTTP protocol RFCs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to either send an HTTP 1.0 header, or else read about content-length in HTTP 1.1. You are reading the stream to EOS when the server is under no obligation to close the connection, so you block. The Content-Length header tells you how much data is in the body: you should only try to read that many bytes.

If you specify HTTP 1.0 (and no fancy headers) the server will close the connection after sending the response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check it. I am just learning Networking Programming so its taking time to understand the things.

Comment: @EJB, Hi EJB we can say,  what exacty the server will do only after seeing the code of server function,  handle_connection(new_fd). This function is mentioned but not provided here in the question.

Comment: @Tanmoy The server has general obligation to implement HTTP 1.0 or 1.1 correctly, whichever it is you are aiming at, possibly both. Clearly at the moment it isn't closing the connection, which means either a bug or that it is attempting to implement HTTP 1.1.